# Error when importing Turtle to python file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a python project and I'm using VS Code.
Any python file I write and include turtle

```
from turtle import *

up()
goto(-200, k)
down()
```

I get errors like:

Undefined variable 'goto'
Undefined variable 'down'
Undefined variable 'forward'
Undefined variable 'left'

I get an error like this for every time I use a turtle element (I got like 100+ total)

The code does work so this isn't crucial, but it just bothers me a bit cause it's just there, you know.

Comment: All of these methods must be called from an instance of a `Turtle`.

Comment: `turtle` is imported, but as 0x5453 said, all of the methods you listed are not at the `Turtle` class level (and not the `turtle` module level), so you need to call them on an instance of a `Turtle` object. Think of it this way, without defining a `Turtle` object, what exactly do you expect to go `up()`?

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
from turtle import *

t = Turtle()
t.up()
# ... etc.
```

You need to create a instance.